# ant Maven task : redirecting output with spawn=true

Tags: maven, ant

a rather clear question here.

I have to launch a Maven job, which is to be run in parallel with ant and it's okay if the job outlives the ant process, hence spawn="true".

I have to see the job output at the end of the Maven build like build is successful or got failure. This is perfectly achievable for spawn="false", but I am kinda out of luck having spawn"=true".

So, is there any solution for this? Please help me out

Comment: If you set `spawn="true"` Ant will not be able to capture the output. This is explained in the `exec` task's documentation: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using Apache's Maven Ant Tasks rather than `exec` http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/

Comment: maven.apache.org/ant-tasks. when I tried to open this it is showing->This component is retired. It is no longer maintained. Is there any other alternative to use so that I can capture the output and do the work of spawn="true"?